# downgrading Heroku SpringBoot template to Java 1.7

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, heroku

I created an app on Heroku using the Heroku "Java Getting Started" template available here: https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started. It was working fine.

Later I decided that I needed to use Java 1.7 instead of 1.8. So I set  `java.runtime.version=1.7` in `system.properties` and also `java.version` under `properties` in my pom.xml.

Unfortunately now it is not compiling (it uses Maven). When I push to Heroku it will download a bunch of Maven dependencies and then die with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:build-info
>   (default) on project myservice: Execution default of goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:build-info
>   failed: Unable to load the mojo 'build-info' in the plugin
>   'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE' due
>   to an API incompatibility:
>   org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
>   org/springframework/boot/maven/BuildInfoMojo : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 52.0 
>   [ERROR] ----------------------------------------------------- 
>   [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE

I understand that the "unsupported major.minor version" component of the error message is a difference between Java 1.7 and Java 1.8, but I don't know where else to change the Java version to 1.7. Or maybe it's that some of the plugins require Java 1.8 to function? I'm not really sure, but I haven't specified a version for my `org.springframework.boot` dependencies in my pom.xml.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example uses Spring Boot 2.0, which does not support Java 7.